# How to set some flags on my node build

Tags: node.js, heroku, codeship

When I build, test and deploy my node application from Codeship to Heroku I want to be able to set a release flag to true using a command line during the build. And in my code I want to do something like this....

```
if(config.release) load(liveConnection);
else load(debugConnection);
```

How can I achieve this? Is there some sort of package I install to run a build script which will transform my config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a config file, you should use environment variables. For example:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

Then, in node:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') load(etc);
```

An even better way is to just provide connection information uniformly, through config files, like this:

```
heroku config:set CONNECTION_STRING=foo
```

Then in node:

```
load(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING);
```

That way, the environment is providing the config. Locally, you can start the app with a development string like `CONNECTION_STRING=some_debug_string node server.js`, or you can use a `.env` file to provide a whole set of them. More info here:

http://12factor.net/config